# Getting Form coordinates within class

Tags: c#, draw, mouse-position

Basically I have created a Class with a method that is called everytime there is a click on my form(it is supposed to draw a single line where I clicked) it goes as follows:

```
public void Dessiner(Graphics Fg)
{

    Point p = Form1.MousePosition;
    Fg.DrawLine(MyPen,p.X,p.Y,p.X+2,p.Y+2);
}
```

The problem is when I call this method within my Forms' mousedown event it places the line at the wrong spot everytime.

Notes: the method can only take the graphics Fg, and the drawing of the line MUST be done within the method of the class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you get Fg from?

Comment: Sorry about that Fg is the instance of my graphics that was declared in my form:

Comment: Fg is the instance of my graphics class that I created in my form so basically (within the form) Fg=this.createGraphics(); and it is used as the parameter for my method afterwards.

Comment: When you say wrong spot, can you be more specific?

Comment: Lets say i click in the middle of the Form it will put the line an inch lower to the right, but the change is relatively random

Comment: Are you drawing on the form, or on a control?

Comment: The drawing is done directly on the form(which contains a menu bar if that changes anything)

Comment: Note that [MousePosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the result in screen (not form) relative coordinates.

Comment: Yeah I realised that but I couldnt find another way of getting any type of coordinate.

Comment: convert the MousePosition to control position using form.PointToClient(...)

Comment: The problem is I cant seem to be able to access PointToClient() within my method. I try to call Form1.PointToClient but get nothing, only option that makes sense in those given is MousePosition.

Comment: Also your Form1 object is the default instance of your form, it is **not** the form you are looking at, you will need to pass in your actual form object.

Comment: Ok thats what ive seen but cant seem to understand, how can I get any type of handle for a form that is only create at the beginning of the program?

Comment: Your MouseDown event handler's `e` argument has information about the coordinate of the event in its properties `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Just add another parameter to your method, either pass in the Form instance or the mouse coordinates like @500-InternalServerError suggests.

Comment: I know i could do that but I specified that the method could only take the instance of Graphics as parameter no other. Also how would i access the event handler e from within the method of my class?

Comment: you said that the method is "called everytime there is a click" on the form.  so why can't you pass it the click event args?  It'd probably help if you give us more code context.

Comment: I am restricted by a rule where as the method from my class can only accept as a parameter the Grahphics Fg, nothing else and the drawing of the line must be done within this method.

Comment: Is this class initialized in your form? If so is it permissible with the restrictions that you are specifying to create a constructor and pass in the instance of the  owner/parent form to it when your class is initialized. That way your class will have knowledge of your Form.

Comment: I think that is allowed how would go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the coordinates with `PointToClient()`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DrawingHelper dh;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dh=new DrawingHelper(this);

    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dh.Desser(this.CreateGraphics());
    }
}

public class DrawingHelper
{
    Form form;
    public DrawingHelper(Form form)
    {
        this.form  =form;
    }
    public void Desser(Graphics Fg)
    {
        var pt=form.PointToClient(Form.MousePosition);
        Fg.DrawLine(Pens.Black, pt.X,pt.Y, pt.X+2, pt.Y+2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help I never completely understood how to use the current form! Great help from all!!!